# Java, cut off array line before charactern nr. X

Tags: java, arrays, string, break

So i have massive(i mean massive) array. It has over 500000 lines.
Each line starts with some bs that i don't need. What i need is EVERYTHING after 64th symbol(65th symbol is needed). It's the same for every line, but after 64th symbol each line lenght is different. How do i get symbols form 65 and on...?
It's ok by me if everything else is deleted but those symbols after 64th character stay in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringArrAC.length; i++)
        {
            if (i<=64)
            {
                stringArrAC[i] = null;
                break;
            }
        }
```

something like this? but its not working... 
Thanks for help. :)

EDIT.. I NEED MORE HELP 
So im back..

i GOT MY 500000 plus lines to the way i want them.. now i need to find second to last word in each line(they are divided by space) and find 3 most popular of them and find how many are there.... Can You help me in any way?

```
data example:
abcd i
asd ffdds abcd ddd ?
abcd ffdds asd ddd i
ddd abcd i
a f g w e a asdfasdasdas fdd i
```

answer that i need:

```
abcd 2
ddd 2
fdd 1

or
2 abcd
2 ddd
1 fdd
```

This is my code

```
public class asdf {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        String str;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            if (str.startsWith(" ")&& str.endsWith("i")||str.endsWith("?")) {

                list.add(str);
                }                  
        } 
        String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);//for backup
        String[] stringArrAC = list.toArray(new String[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < stringArrAC.length; i++)
        {
            stringArrAC[i] = stringArrAC[i].substring(63);
        }
        //String[] stringArrLAST = (new String[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArrAC.length; i++)
        {

            // THIS IS WHERE I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO
        }
        try
        {
            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter("output.txt");  
            for (int i=0; i<stringArrAC.length ; i++)
            {
                pr.println(stringArrAC[i]);
            }
            pr.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("No such file exists.");
        }
                }
```

Comment: This is an array of strings? And you're wanting to erase the first 64 characters of each string?

Comment: "(i mean massive) array. It has over 500000 lines." Arrays doesn't have lines, they have elements. Also your question looks like you may be looking for `substring` method, but I am not entirely sure about it since it is not very clean. Could you add simplified example of your input and expected output?

Comment: Shar1er80 YOU are right .. thats what i want

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: RamanShrivastava has already given you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it is an String array, below code should do

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringArrAC.length; i++) {
    stringArrAC[i] = stringArrAC[i].substring(64);
}
```

Comment: @Eiseps Then click the check mark next to his answer, so your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the end of a string, you could just use the substring() method.  In this case, it would look like

```
stringMinus64 = stringArrAC.substring(65)
```

You wouldn't even need the for loop.
documentation is here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm